# Fixed column width on Datatables when scrollX is enabled

Tags: datatables

I have a dynamically filled datatable with fixed columns and scrollX enabled:

```js
$('#products').DataTable({
        "data": formattedData,
        "scrollX": true, 
        "fixedColumns":{ "leftColumns": 0, "rightColumns": 1 }
});
```

The problem is, I need the columns to stop automatically calculating their width. Even if I try to force them on initialization...

```js
$('#products').DataTable({
  "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
  "columnDefs": [ 
    { "title": "Name", "targets": 0, "width": "350px" },
    { "title": "Code", "targets": 1 },
    { "title": "Regular code", "targets": 2, "width": "500px" },
    { "title": "Special code", "targets": 3, "width": "300px" }
  ]
});
```

... if scrollX is enabled, the scrolling is enabled just if the columns are too small. And I want the scrolling enaled always, and the columns not changing their width.

Any idea about how to force the column width?

The same question was asked here but has no answer: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31403/scrollx-not-work-with-fixed-column-width

Answer (score 4):

First disable **`autoWidth`** -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth

In my humble opinion `columns.width` are useless to anything than relative percentages. Define minimum column widths in CSS instead

```css
#products td:nth-child(1) { min-width: 350px; }
#products td:nth-child(3) { min-width: 500px; }
#products td:nth-child(4) { min-width: 300px; }
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/f8uw6rLy/**